# Blender Grease Pencil - Faux Closed Shape

Tags: grease-pencil

I am just starting out with blender grease pencil
and I have been using the curve tool in Draw Mode a lot.
However after drawing the shape, I often want it to be a closed shape,
so in Edit Mode I would select the two end points and press F to set cyclic state,
which connects the points. But then on one previous end there is still a rounded edge, made very obvious through the fill.
How do I get rid of this weird little corner? Has anyone had the same issue?[image]

Comment: To specify - I am using Holdout for the Stroke, as I need a clear line. The issue actually goes away when I don't use Hold out and use a regular colored stroke.